# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error when running project

Tags: ios, breakpoints

when i run my project i get the following error, Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code:EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0. I will post code below but does anyone know how to fix this?

it appears on a ***let type = PFUser.currentUser()!["Type"] as? String***

```css
 import UIKit
    import Parse
    import ParseUI

    
    class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {
        
    var usersLocation: PFGeoPoint? {
            didSet {
                // This will reload the tableview when you set the users location.
                // Handy if you want to keep updating it.z
                if (tableView != nil) {
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        
        override func  viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            
        }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
            }

        // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
        override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
            super.init(style: style, className: className)
        }
        
        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            
            
            // Configure the PFQueryTableView
            self.parseClassName = "User"
            self.textKey = "fullName"
            self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
            self.paginationEnabled = false
            
            
            
        }
        
        // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
        override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery{
            
            let type = PFUser.currentUser()!["Type"] as? String
            let age = PFUser.currentUser()!["Age"] as? String
            let fitnessLevel = PFUser.currentUser()!["fitnessLevel"] as? String
            
            var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
            query.whereKey("Type", equalTo: type!)
            query.whereKey("Age", equalTo: age!)
            query.whereKey("fitnessLevel", equalTo: fitnessLevel!)
            
            
            // If we don't have a location, just query without it.
            if let geoLocation = usersLocation {
                query.whereKey("geoLocation", nearGeoPoint:geoLocation)
            }
            query.limit = 100
            return query
        }
        
        //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
            
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomCell!
            if cell == nil {
                cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
            }
            
            // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
            if let name = object?["fullName"] as? String {
                cell.name.text = name
            }
            if let type = object?["lookingFor"] as? String {
                cell.type.text = type
            }
            if let location = object?["location"] as? String {
                cell.location.text = location
            }
            
            let cover = object?["cover"] as! PFFile
            cover.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            let profile_pic = object?["profile_pic"] as! PFFile
            profile_pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `currentUser()` is `nil`, that causes the crash while unwrapping (`!`) it.
Use optional bindings:

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
  let type = user["Type"] as? String
  let age = user["Age"] as? String
  let fitnessLevel = user["fitnessLevel"] as? String
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for you help but when i do this it works but the 3 lines below the strings are an "unresolved identifier"

Comment: If the user is nil there is no need at all to perform the query, I recommend to check if `currentUser` is nil before `queryForTable()` is called

Comment: Thanks im using PFloginvieecontroller at the beginning to sign in/up the user but the login screen is not loading because of this error so i cant logon which then in turn causes this error. Do you know how to fix this

Comment: I guess `queryForTable()` is always called when the table view is refreshed  so try to check in `usersLocation ` :  `if (tableView != nil && PFUser.currentUser() != nil ) { tableView.reloadData() }`